# How to run one Cucumber (With Protractor) scenario over multiples files?

Tags: protractor, cucumber, e2e-testing, cucumberjs, gulp-protractor

I have a Cucumber feature like this one:

```
@MainSuite
Scenario: Verify that user can login
  Given I can see the login form
  Then I set a username
  And I set a password
  And I click in Login button
  Then I see the "wrong-password" message
```

I need to check that the user can login in 5 different pages.
I need to run that feature in 5 different places.
It's like, I need to run that feature in /login.html, /old_login.html, /after_restore_password.html and more (it's just an example).

Do you know how to do it?

Currently, I have only one file hardcoded. Obviously I need to change it.

```
this.Given(/^I can see the login form$/, function(done) {
    this.goTo('login.html');
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(this.loginFormContainer));
    done();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object containing the different login pages that you can go to.

Include an if statement in your step def if there is any extra code that needs to be executed.

```
this.Given(/^I can see the "(.*)" login form$/, function(loginPage, done) {
    var logins = {
         login : "login.html",
         afterpasswordreset: "after-password-reset.html"
    }
    loginPage = loginPage.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
    this.goTo(logins[loginPage]);
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(this.loginFormContainer));
    done();
});
```

Make either separate Scenarios or feature file for each variation of login, or simply create a Scenario Outline for them

**EDIT**

Here is how I would implement the Scenario Outline:

```
@MainSuite
Scenario Outline: Verify that user can login
  Given I can see the "<loginType>" login form
  And I set a username
  And I set a password
  When I click in Login button
  Then I see the "wrong-password" message

 Examples:
    | loginType              |
    | Login                  |
    | After Password Reset   |
```

Comment: Nop. You will have 2 execution of the Given rule, but then only one for each next line (When's and Then's)

Comment: How do you mean? Given When Then doesn't always have to be in sets of three. That in itself is a misconception. It has to be descriptive enough to follow, which is why the "And" and "But" syntax rules are in place.

Comment: Check the escenario I wrote in the main question. How will you write the cucumber-escenario with your proposal? (edit your answer with the example. you will see that there is a problem.)

Comment: I think I understood what you meant by the 2 execution of the given step, but only one for each of the next lines. For Scenario Outlines, you can write the same scenario but with minor tweaks using an examples table (as shown in the answer). This will actually run the Scenario as many times as there are non-header rows, moving down the table, using the rows values in the Scenario that it runs. This works perfectly for logins across the site, if the steps are the same.

Comment: You are the man. I didn't realized the existence of "Scenario Outline". Thank you so much!